# How to change the CSS Class property dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I setup my tagfield value by using class,

```
.x-tagfield-input-field {
    width: 3px;
}
```

I want to change width after selecting first element.

```
select : function(tag){
    var tagClass = component.inputCell.dom.getElementsByClassName("x-tagfield-input");

}
```

How to change the width after first element selection?

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS provides `addCls()` method to add class dynamically. If you are giving width in class then add new class as `tagClass.addCls(<new class name>)`. If you want to specify width on the fly then use `setWidth()` as `tagClass.setWidth(width in pixels)`.

Check this and reply.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the way he can use this.